# Does a downloaded .exe file containing malware typically cause problems if it is not opened? If so, why/how?

Tags: windows-7, malware

My friend accidentally downloaded an .exe file containing malware, but did not double-click it. However, his system is now slowing down and his browser is giving him an error message that was clearly written by the malware creator.

It is common advice to not download suspicious .exe files from the web and then execute them by double clicking on them. However, I was under the impression that the download itself, i.e., the sole act of a file being copied from the network to disk itself, does not cause any problems as long as the machine-level instructions of the malware program are not executed (and I was under the impression that the only way to do this is by actually telling the OS to run the .exe explicitly via the GUI or the command line).

It's also known that opening static files like images and documents can cause problems by means of zero-day exploits/vulnerabilities (for example in the metadata). However, in an updated system this should be extremely rare.

How can an executable that's just sitting on disk somehow magically execute itself? Are there some kind of metadata instructions present that the OS will run upon file creation or copy? How typical is this behavior in malware today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, typically not. If a downloaded application is not run or opened in any way, how can it execute it's code? It can't... Anti-virus and Anti-Malware software will (hopefully) still find it and clean/remove it. That isn't to say it is not possible, properly named windows and some other operating systems may execute/mount/open a file or location automatically.

Best bet stay away and do no not download it, if you did download an infected file but did not open/execute it and you caught it some how just delete it and continue on, but if you opened it or executed the file, be very careful and proceed as if you have potentially been infected.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for commenting on a really old post, but since this pops up on google I don't want anyone to be mislead.

I have downloaded .exe files from trusted sites before that will not run unless you double click them. But I have also accidentally downloaded .exe files from random sites a couple of times, and noticed that they would automatically run and request administrator access. Probably not by coincidence, every time this had happened a windows update was released that I decided to delay, and when the file downloaded in the time I decide not to update windows yet, the .exe file would run itself. I would then not be able to drag it to the recycle bin and delete it due to it being open, and would either try restarting my computer, or closing it with task manager in order to delete it.

I feel its possible, but not likely. I'm guessing if I had updated windows when the update was released, the file would of probably not been able to bypass windows security. To be safe - everyone keep windows and their anti-virus software updated!